# Regular expression matches an incomplete expression

Tags: java, regex, string-matching

I'd like to write the regular expression to recognize the series tv episode; I'm doing this in Java. Titles are written this way:

```
Title 2x05
```

Where 2 is the season and 5 is the episode; so I used this expression:

```
\d*x\d*
```

And it works perfectly fine, except when the title includes one or more "x" character; in this case I have a match exactly on this character, causing obvious problems. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to match any number of `x` in between season and episode? If yes, try

```
\d+x+\d+
```

use `+` instead of `*` to make sure there is at least one digit for season and episode and at lease one `x` in between.

Comment: In that case `\d+x\d+` is what you need. Using `+` instead of `*` will stop the matching with `Title` unless you have somethins like `2x05` inside the `Tile`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, especially if you actually *do* want to match zero or more digits around `x`: Use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

```
\b\d*x\d*\b
```

will match `2x5`, `x3`, `25x` or even `x`, but it won't match the `x` in `text` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression instead "`\d+x\d+`".

Note that the `+` character will match *one or more* of the preceding token (a digit) whereas the `*` will match *zero or more* of the preceding token.

Answer (score 0):

You can even use groups to simultaneously retrieve the season and episode informations :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*(\\d+)x(\\d+).*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Series 2x08");
if (matcher.matches()) {
    int season = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
    int episode = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
    System.out.printf("Season %d, Episode %d", season, episode);
}
```

Result : Season 2, Episode 8

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`\d+x\d+`

`+` : 1 or more

`*` : 0 or more

`?` : 1 or not at all

But remember that this is not the most robust method to test in your case. If someone enters 99x9999999, that will be 99th season and 9999999 episode. If you want to limit the number of possible seasons and episodes, [check here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html).

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
[0-9]{1,2}x[0-9]{1,3}
```

Assuming there are not more than 99 seasons and more than 999 episodes per season.